# Notices in PHP. How to did not show them?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, notifications, error-reporting

I has function which deleting the file. It is my code:

```
echo error_reporting();     // got 32767 = E_ALL, yes?
ini_set('display_errors',0);
if(unlink($file) == false){
    echo "Error";
}
```

And I am getting the following error:

> string(274) "PROBLEM  unlink(/path/to/file.mp4): Permission denied in
>   /path/to/script.php on line 1226

How can I log my errors on log file, but not on the screen?

Comment: Change php_ini to log_errors=on display_errors=off log_file=/Some/File/Somewhere

Comment: Anigel, can i set log_errors at runtime? I was tryed my code with these on first line:  ini_set('log_errors',1); - and i still see notification...

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own error handler with [function set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

You can write logging in the function passed to set_error_handler()

This function has also param called **error_types** where you can provide what kind of errors you want to handle. It's up to you if you display them or not.

I won't write about other options because they were already mentioned by others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `error_log()` and for suppress the error in frontend you can use `error_reporting(0)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is because in PHP 5.2.4 and up the variable has changed from boolean to string. Set display_errors to 'stderr' instead.

Answer (score 0):

**→ Try this:**

This will work at runtime:

```
     ini_set( 'display_errors', '0' );
```

This will stop errors from being displayed but they will still be logged. This will stop both:

```
     error_reporting(0); // Will stop both error displaying and reporting to screen
```

Answer (score 0):

It was var_dump() on other script which catching errors and show it on screen.